# Method is not gettting mocked (Mockito.when().thenReturn()) and not returning specified mock value

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I am writing test case for a protected method, the method is called

```
protected boolean printMultipleImages(int rows, int cols, IIOImage[] imgs,
                                      PrintMode mode, AutomaticCroppingOption crop,
                                      double reduction, int renderOption)
```

Within this method an array variable is getting initialized, the following piece of code shows how

```
RenderRequest request = this.formSlotsRenderRequest(rows, cols, imgs,mode, crop, reduction);
        // Create a Printer Properties Object...
        PrinterProperties prop = this.getAutoPrinterProperties();
        // Get the Appropriate Print Rendering Engine..
        MultiFilmPrintRenderer engine = this.getPrintRenderer();

        MultiFilmRenderRequest multiFilmRenderRequest = new MultiFilmRenderRequest(renderOption, request,new ChoppingPreferences());

        assert engine != null;

        RenderedImage[] rImageArr =engine.renderAcrossFilms(multiFilmRenderRequest, prop); //NPE here, rImageArr=null, though I mocked the method to return something.
```

in line highlighted below, the variable `rImageArr` is not getting initialized and is holding null,
the method call  `engine.renderAcrossFilms(multiFilmRenderRequest, prop);` is giving me null even when I mock it to return something and the control is going inside the method and giving Null Pointer Exception, which should not happen since I am mocking it. All the variabales used here are local to the method.

```
RenderedImage[] rImageArr =engine.renderAcrossFilms(multiFilmRenderRequest, prop);
```

This is how I mocked the method `engine.renderAcrossFilms(multiFilmRenderRequest, prop);`

```
@Test
    public void testPrintMultipleImages() throws Exception
    {
        //MultiFilmRenderRequest req=Mockito.mock(MultiFilmRenderRequest.class);
        MultiFilmPrintRenderer engine=Whitebox.getInternalState(autoPrintEndPoint, "_engine");//new JCPrintRenderEngine();//
        System.out.println(engine+"here");

        RenderedImage[] renderAcrossFilms=new RenderedImage[]{Mockito.mock(RenderedImage.class)};
        PrinterProperties prop=Mockito.mock(PrinterProperties.class);
        RenderRequest renderRequest=Mockito.mock(RenderRequest.class);
        AutomaticCroppingOption crop=Mockito.mock(AutomaticCroppingOption.class);
        PrintMode mode=Mockito.mock(PrintMode.class);
        IIOImage img=Mockito.mock(IIOImage.class);

        MultiFilmRenderRequest multiFilmRenderRequest = new MultiFilmRenderRequest(1, renderRequest,
                                     new ChoppingPreferences());

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(autoPrintEndPoint,PowerMockito.method(AutoPrintEndPoint.class,"loadImage", IIOImage.class)).withArguments(img);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(renderRequest).when(autoPrintEndPoint,PowerMockito.method(AutoPrintEndPoint.class,"formSlotsRenderRequest", int.class, int.class, IIOImage[].class,PrintMode.class,AutomaticCroppingOption.class,double.class)).withArguments(2,2,new IIOImage[]{img},mode,crop,12.5);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(prop).when(autoPrintEndPoint,PowerMockito.method(AutoPrintEndPoint.class,"getAutoPrinterProperties")).withNoArguments();
              Mockito.when(engine.renderAcrossFilms(Mockito.any(MultiFilmRenderRequest.class),Mockito.any(PrinterProperties.class))).thenReturn(renderAcrossFilms);

        Method printMultipleImages=AutoPrintEndPoint.class.getDeclaredMethod("printMultipleImages", int.class,int.class,IIOImage[].class,PrintMode.class,AutomaticCroppingOption.class,double.class,int.class);
        printMultipleImages.setAccessible(true);
        printMultipleImages.invoke(autoPrintEndPoint,2,2,new IIOImage[]{img},mode,crop,12.5,1);

    }
```

I hope I am clear enough in my question, I hope you can help me

Comment: How did you define the variable `renderAcrossFilms`?

Comment: Also, have you tried using any() matchers for your parameters?

Comment: @muzzlator `RenderedImage[] renderAcrossFilms=new RenderedImage[]{Mockito.mock(RenderedImage.class)};` and I haven't used any matchers.

Comment: I'm confused now Akhil, maybe some debugging statements to clarify exactly what you're seeing? Where are you getting the NPE? Feel free to add more code to your post

Comment: @muzzlator I have highlighted the line where I am getting NPE, in the last line of 2nd piece of code that I have posted above.

Comment: Akhil, you still haven't shown where you're calling Mockito.when so I can't understand how the various parts of your code are put together. Put *all* the relevant parts of your code in the one listing and not scattered around

Comment: I have put the relevant parts of my test case. you can have a look

Comment: sorry but you still haven't given enough detail :/ Why don't you put complete  methods for all the relevant  parts of the code? For example, where are you calling  printMultipleImages in your test? How are you supplying the mocks from the test method into the actual method? None of these are clear from the way you've described the question

Comment: It's getting late, I'm going to bed. Hopefully there will be more details here in the morning, or you have the solution to your problem by then.

Comment: OK, Now, how is the `MultiFilmPrintRenderer` mock passed into the real method? Moreover, why are you not mocking the `MultiFilmPrintRenderer`? You seem to be calling `Whitebox.getInternalState`? How do you intend to call `Mockito.when(engine.foo)` when engine is not a mock object? Include print statements and put a comment saying `// Expected: "this" Actual "this"`. Give as much information as you can instead of incrementally adding bits and bobs here and there, it'll speed up this drawn out conversation

Comment: The problem is solved. I created a mock on `engine` and did a `setInternalState`. It worked out

Comment: Nice! Please add your answer to the list of answers or edit the question with the conclusion :) People might gloss over this conversation and begin to answer it themselves

Answer (score 0):

within the method that you are going to test,
it creates the new instance

```
MultiFilmRenderRequest multiFilmRenderRequest = new MultiFilmRenderRequest(renderOption, request,new ChoppingPreferences());
```

and this will be used as a parameter of the mocked method.
but you might have mocked the method providing a arguments which is not equal to arguments that the printMultipleImages method pass to the engine.

other than this i can see 
PrinterProperties prop=Mockito.mock(PrinterProperties.class);

but this mock class has not been used, so again the target test method might send a different PrinterProperties object.

you can use

engine.renderAcrossFilms(Mockito.any(MultiFilmRenderRequest.class),Mockito.any(PrinterProperties.class))

Comment: I have passed the same parameter In my mock as well, but it still throws a NPE

Comment: how did you pass the same parameter, because first parameter is created within the method just before the it calls to engine.renderAcrossFilms, so how did you access that value.

Comment: I called the constructor the same way its called within the method and passed that as the parameter. I have edited the post and shown the prameters I have passed. U can just have a look. I am still an amateur at this and still learning so please bare with the mistakes.

Comment: so that means you have overriden the equal(Object) method in MultiFilmRenderRequest?

Comment: No I just tried to make the parameters same as what are passed in the method under test. I have tried passing mock object as well , but even then the mock does not work.

Comment: then , Mockito will not identify this as the same prameter, but there is way that you can use,without specifying the parameter, you can use  Mockito.any() , i have edited my answer

Comment: I made the change you suggested and I am still getting NPE, I have now edited the post and added my entire test case. Do go through it

Answer (score 0):

I will continue to expand this answer as you give more details but based on your latest update, you have:

```
MultiFilmPrintRenderer engine =
    Whitebox.getInternalState(autoPrintEndPoint, "_engine");
// ...
Mockito.when(engine.renderAcrossFilms(multiFilmRenderRequest, prop))
    .thenReturn(renderAcrossFilms);
```

So is this Whitebox.getInternalState returning a mock object or not?

Comment: It is giving me null. I have tried mocking the object rather then doing a getInternalState but still the mock doesn't work and gives me NPE

Comment: Why are these in the same code block in your question?

Comment: I have now added the entire test case. Hopefully the problem I am facing will be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I created a mock on the `engine` object that was being used to call the method I was trying to mock and did a setInternalState.

```
MultiFilmPrintRenderer engine = Mockito
                .mock(MultiFilmPrintRenderer.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(autoPrintEndPoint, "_engine", engine);
```

This way the mock object was set. and the NPE was resolved